# How to update files in my computer whenever they get updated in github?

Tags: file, github, localhost, git-hash

I know this might sound stupid but I couldn't find a solution on the Internet.
I'm working on a project in GitHub and every time someone adds a new file or some new code I have to download the whole files on my computer in order to open them from my local host.

As you can imagine this is really tiring and I know there are easier ways to update the files.
Could anyone please propose an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

The normal workflow is simply to do a `git pull` on demand (assuming those files are pushed on the same branch as the one you are working on).

That means, whenever you are ready, you make a `git pull` and get the updated files that way.
It is a pull workflow, not a push (from GitHub) workflow.

That being said, if you need a local repository with *always* the latest files updated (again, from a specific branch), you would setup a [`GitHub webhook`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/webhooks-and-events/about-webhooks) whic, on each push, would notify a listener on your machine, triggering from that listener a `git pull`.

See this [gist for an example](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/619858), executed from an local web server in php.
A more [complete example here](https://gist.github.com/webjay/3915531).

You can use any language to setup a listener/server on your machine, which will be contacted by GitHub.
See "[Webhook to auto-deploy on git push to Github](https://dev.to/rrampage/webhook-to-auto-deploy-on-git-push-to-github-330i) " as a detailed example, using a web server in [Go](https://golang.org/).